# Python import module from a subfolder that imports a sibling module

Tags: python, import, nested, siblings

Folder structure:

```
ABC
|--db
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- post.py
|   |-- common.py
|   |-- connection.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- main.py
```

From main.py I want to import post.py in the db folder.
Inside post.py I import some functions from common.py.

main.py contents:
`from db import post`

post.py contents:
`from common import table_insert,get_row`

Running main.py gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ABC/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from db import post
  File "/home/user/ABC/db/post.py", line 1, in <module>
    from common import table_insert,get_row
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

**Additional info:**

- /home/user/ABC is in the sys.path
- `__init__.py` files are empty

I've tried searching for a general description in the python documentation for how to import other modules that in turn imports other modules. No luck . I've searched Stackoverflow for similar cases - No luck finding any useable answers

Comment: `from .common import table_insert, get_row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

Changed the import statement in post.py to be fully qualified.

From

```
from common import table_insert,get_row
```

To

```
from db.common import table_insert,get_row
```

Answer (score 1):

In `post.py`, you must use relative import:

```
from .common import table_insert, get_row
```

Use of relative import is to refer in the same dir as `post.py` i.e `db` dir.

If you want to run individually you could do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from common import table_insert,get_row
else:
    from .common import table_insert, get_row
```

Comment: tried it. running the post.py alone with your suggestion gives me:     from .common import table_insert,get_row
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package